# How Django ORM, REST API and a Web app stack up?

Tags: django, api, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to develop a web application in Django including a REST API and also a web application to allow user to login and see stuff. I'm a bit confused as to how these are connected together.

I'm thinking that Django ORM is at the bottom and on top of that comes the API and then the web app uses the API to generate HTML. Is this correct understanding? A `yes` or `no` with few {key}words explanation would be enough.

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Django ORM is the bottom layer in your app as it will make possible to manipulate your data. When it comes to APIs, the main goal is to make accessible and manipulable your data from different devices (clients), for instance your web app and your iOS app may consume the same API and that will reduce your implementation time and eventually it will give you a better integration through your different clients and devices. Last but not least, the Web app is at this point the consumer to your API and your front-end.

You could check [Tastypie](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)/ in order to implement your API and for your web app you have plenty of frameworks that you could use as Backbone, AngularJS etc.